# React Native Navigation Passing back parameters two screen pop

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a Screen for Main then it's push to Next for selection and passes parameters to next pushed screen and when you select something in that screen I need to `pop(2)` and send selected details to the main screen.

But `pop` didn't accept parameters. How to accomplish this.

I don't use Redux or MobX.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this

Screen A:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB', {
              onPressScreenAFun: (params) => {
                this.screenAFun(params)
              },
            })

screenAFun = (params) => {
console.log(params)
}
```

Screen B:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenC', {
                  onPressScreenBFun: (params) => {
                    this.screenBFun(params)
                  },
                })

    screenBFun = (params) => {
       const { onPressScreenAFun } = this.props.navigation.navigate.state.params

      onPressScreenAFun(params)
      this.props.navigation.goBack()
    }
```

Screen C:

```
    moveBack = (params) => {
       const { onPressScreenBFun } = this.props.navigation.navigate.state.params

      onPressScreenBFun(params)
      this.props.navigation.goBack()
    }
```

this is how you can pass params from Screen C to Screen A with two pop()

Comment: Will try this and get back to you. For now, I used Navigate to the Main screen with params.

Comment: Did you check this?