# Flatlist is not updated?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
    class Parent extends React.Component {
      constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={data:[]}
      }
      componentDidMount(){         
     / * I am loading data from the server * /
        } 
      ratingCompleted=(id,favourite,i)=>{
        if(favourite===0){
           CustomerApi.AddFavourite(id);
         }
         else{
           let newState = Object.assign({}, this.state.JSON_from_server);
           newState[i].favourite = 0; 
           this.setState({JSON_from_server:newState,refresh:!this.state.refresh});}}
    render(){
     return(
        <Child data={this.state.data} refresh={this.state.refresh} 
         ratingCompleted={this.ratingCompleted}/>
    )
    }
   }
```

Child component

```
class Child extends React.Component {
      constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={refresh:this.props.refresh}
      }
       renderItem(data) {     
let {item, index}  = data;      
let i=this.props.JSON_from_server.indexOf(item); 
    render(){
  return(
    <View>
    <AirbnbRating  count={1} defaultRating={item.favourite} size={30} showRating={false} onFinishRating={()=>{this.props.ratingCompleted(item.id,item.favourite,i);}}/>
    </View>
 )
}
}
     <FlatList  
                   keyExtractor = {( item, index ) => index.id }
                   data = { this.props.data}
                   renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
                   extraData={this.props.refresh}{
                  / * set even extraData = {this.props}, extraData = 
                    {this.state.refresh} or even subscribed to the parent 
                     component so the update did not work. * /}                   
            />
    )
    }
   }
```

And when the data in the Parent component changes, the Child does not change. Used for Parent shouldcomponentDidUpdate did not work. **In short, how can I update the flatlist if in a child component?**

Comment: In the parent component you are render `<Parent ...`, shouldn't be `<Child>` component?

Comment: sorry corrected

Comment: How you are updating `this.state.data`? Can you please share code of your update function?

Comment: You have to share the code as it is in your machine here. I can see you are posting code with all syntax errors. Please share complete code of these components which you have in your machine

Comment: ok here's the complete code

Comment: Who can help? Or did I incorrectly explain the question or the code is not clear?
I can't do a week

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is use ComponentWillRecieveProps in Child Component like this

```
componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps){
if(JSON.stringify(this.props.data) !== JSON.stringify(nextProps.data)){
   this.setState({ updateList: nextProps.data})
}
}
```

then use

```
this.state.updateList
```

for updating the FlatList

You can also call Main Component function explicitly from child component when navigating back, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52581012/7462666) and call setState for re-rendring

Comment: did you log the props?

Comment: I think updating the parent component will itself update the Child component.