# Re-rendering the component after form submit

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I'm creating a **react-native** app with **redux**. In which I have two screens first is **main screen** where all the list of items are there and second is **form screen** where there will be a form. when user submit the form by clicking on **submit button** user should be redirect to **main screen** and that time **main screen** should be re-rendered with previous state and new set of state which is submited.

I have added my file please take a look . after submitting the form when I'm going to main screen it is not displaying new values that I have added, to see what I have added i have to manually refresh the app from terminal then only I'm able to see new values that has been added so what should i do for getting a added values without manually refreshing the app from terminal

**bookAction.js**

```
import {
   FETCHING_BOOKS_REQUEST,
   FETCHING_BOOKS_SUCCESS,
   FETCHING_BOOKS_FAILURE,
   CREATE_BOOKS_REQUEST
} from "./types";
import axios from "axios";


export const fetchingBooksRequest = () => ({
   type:FETCHING_BOOKS_REQUEST
});

export const fetchingBooksSuccess = (data) => ({
   type:FETCHING_BOOKS_SUCCESS,
   payload:data
});


export const fetchingBooksFailure = (error) => ({
   type:FETCHING_BOOKS_FAILURE,
   payload:error
});


export const fetchBooks = () => {
   return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch(fetchingBooksRequest())
        axios.get("http://IpAddress:3000/api/Books")
            .then((response)=>{
                dispatch(fetchingBooksSuccess(response.data))
                // console.log(response.data)
            })
            .catch ((error) =>  {
                dispatch(fetchingBooksFailure(error))
            });
      }
   }
```

**AddBookAction.js**

```
import {
  TITLE_ADD,
  DESCRIPTION_ADD,
  ADD_BOOKS,
  ADD_BOOKS_SUCCESS,
  ADD_BOOKS_FAILURE
} from "./types";
import {Actions} from "react-native-router-flux"



export const titleAdd = (text) => {
   return{
      type:TITLE_ADD,
      payload:text
   };
};

export const descriptionAdd = (text) => {
    return{
       type:DESCRIPTION_ADD,
       payload:text
   };
};

export const createBooks = ({title,description}) => {
   return (dispatch) => {
     dispatch({
        type:ADD_BOOKS
    })
    fetch("http://IPAddress:3000/api/Books",{
        method:"POST",
        headers:{
            "content-type":"application/json"
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({title,description})
     })
      .then(res=>res.json())
      .then(() => {
         dispatch({
             type:ADD_BOOKS_SUCCESS

         });
     })
     .catch((error) => {
         console.log(error)
          dispatch({
            type:ADD_BOOKS_FAILURE
         })
     })
    }
   }
```

**BookReducer.js**

```
import {
  FETCHING_BOOKS_REQUEST,
  FETCHING_BOOKS_SUCCESS,
  FETCHING_BOOKS_FAILURE,
} from "../actions/types";


 const INITIAL_STATE = { 
   books:[],
   loading:false,
   errorMessage:""
};


 export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action)=>{
    console.log(action);
      switch(action.type){
         case FETCHING_BOOKS_REQUEST:
           return { ...state, loading:true };
         case FETCHING_BOOKS_SUCCESS:
           return { ...state, loading:false, books:action.payload };
         case FETCHING_BOOKS_FAILURE:
           return { ...state, loading:true, errorMessage:"error occurs" };
        default:
           return state;
    }
 };
```

**AddbookReducer.js**

```
import {
   TITLE_ADD,
   DESCRIPTION_ADD,
   ADD_BOOKS,
   ADD_BOOKS_SUCCESS,
   ADD_BOOKS_FAILURE
} from "../actions/types";


 const INITIAL_STATE = { 
    title:"",
    description:"",
    error:""
 };


  export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action)=>{
     console.log(action);
      switch(action.type){
        case TITLE_ADD:
          return { ...state, title:action.payload  };
        case DESCRIPTION_ADD:
          return { ...state, description:action.payload  };
        case ADD_BOOKS:
          return { ...state, error:""  };
        case ADD_BOOKS_SUCCESS:
          return { 
            ...state, 
            error:"", 
            title:"", 
            description:""  
         };
        case ADD_BOOKS_FAILURE:
          return { 
            ...state , 
            error:"Can't post data error occur",
            title:"",
            description:""
         }
       default:
         return state;
     }
 };
```

**AddBook.js(form Component)**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
  View, 
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  ScrollView,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity
} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {createBooks,titleAdd,descriptionAdd} from 
"../redux/actions/AddBookActions";
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

class AddBooks extends Component {


 static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
     title: 'Add books',
     headerTintColor: '#ffffff',
     headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: '#2F95D6',
      borderBottomColor: '#ffffff',
      borderBottomWidth: 3,

    },
    headerTitleStyle: {
      fontSize: 18,
    },

});





   onTitleAdd(text){
    this.props.titleAdd(text)
   }

   onDescriptionAdd(text){
    this.props.descriptionAdd(text)
   }

    onButtonPress({navigation}) {
      const { title, description  } = this.props;

    this.props.createBooks({  title, description });

    this.onFormSubmit(this.props)
   }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      this.onFormSubmit(nextProps)
    }

   onFormSubmit({navigation}){
    navigation.navigate("AllBooks")
   }


  render() {
    return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView 
      behavior="padding" 
      style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView>
       <View>
         <TextInput style={styles.textInput} 
                  placeholder="Title"
                  placeholderTextColor="black"
                  underlineColorAndroid="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
                  onChangeText={this.onTitleAdd.bind(this)}
                  value={this.props.title}
         />
       </View>
       <View>
         <TextInput style={styles.textInput} 
                    placeholder="Description"
                    placeholderTextColor="black"
                    underlineColorAndroid="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
                    onChangeText={this.onDescriptionAdd.bind(this)}
                    value={this.props.description}
         />
       </View>
       <TouchableOpacity 
        style={styles.button}
       onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}
       >
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
            Submit 
        </Text>    
       </TouchableOpacity>

      </ScrollView>
     </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </View>
   );
  }
 }

mapStateToProps  = ({addBookReducers}) => {
  const { title,description } = addBookReducers;

  return {
   title,
   description
  }
 }

 export default connect(mapStateToProps,{
    titleAdd,
    descriptionAdd,
    createBooks,

 })(AddBooks)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    backgroundColor:"#EBF5FB",
    flex:1
  },
  textInput:{
    marginTop: 10,
    fontSize:20,
    height:50,
    borderColor:"black", 
    borderWidth: 1,
    width:"100%"
 },
 button:{
  width:"100%",
  backgroundColor: "#19B5FE",
  marginVertical: 10,
  paddingVertical: 16,
  borderRadius: 30,
 },
 buttonText:{
    fontSize:16,
    fontWeight:"500",
    textAlign:"center",
    color:"black"

  },
})
```

**AllBooks.js(main screen component)**

```
          import React, { Component } from 'react';
      import { 
        View, 
        Text, 
        StyleSheet, 
        ScrollView, 
        KeyboardAvoidingView,
        ActivityIndicator,
        TouchableOpacity
      } from 'react-native';
      import { fetchBooks } from "../redux/actions/BooksActions";
      import { connect } from "react-redux";
      import {PropTypes} from "prop-types";
      import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome"

      class AllBooks extends Component {

        componentWillMount() {
          this.props.fetchBooks()
        }




        render() {
          const { error, loading, Books } = this.props;
          if (error) {
            return(
              <View style={ styles.container }>
                <Text>{error}</Text>
              </View>
            )
          }
          if(loading){
            return(
              <View style={ styles.container }>
                <ActivityIndicator size={50} color="blue"/>
              </View>
            )
          };

          return (

            <View style={styles.scrollViewWrapper}>
              <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>

                <View style={styles.mainView}>
                  {Books.map((book) =>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                    key={book._id}
                    style={styles.paticularView}
                    >
                      <Text style={styles.text}>{book.title}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  )}
                </View>
              </ScrollView>
            </View> 

          );
        }
      };

      AllBooks.propTypes = {
        fetchBooks:PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        Books:PropTypes.array.isRequired
      }


      mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return { 
          Books:state.bookReducers.books,
          error:state.bookReducers.errorMessage,
          loading:state.bookReducers.loading
        }
      }


      export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchBooks} )(AllBooks);

      const styles = StyleSheet.create({
          scrollViewWrapper:{
            flex:1,
          },
          scrollView:{
            paddingTop: 20,
            flex:1
          },
          mainView:{
            height:"100%",
          },
          paticularView:{
            height:80,
            borderWidth: 2,
            borderRadius: 2,
            borderColor: '#E5E7E9',
            borderBottomWidth: 0,
            shadowColor: '#000',
            shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 3 },
            shadowOpacity: 0.8,
            shadowRadius: 2,
            elevation: 1,
            marginLeft: 5,
            marginRight: 5,
            marginTop: 10,

          },
          text:{
            fontSize:18,
            marginLeft:5,
            marginTop:5
          }
      });
```

Comment: So you want to update main screen with new State or send data from form screen to main Screen?

Comment: @HaiderAli I want to send data from form screen to main screen after form submit it should be redirect to main screen and the new value that has been submitted should be display in main screen

Comment: You need to handle the sent action with payload (the form data) inside the main reducer then add this to the main state.
Imagine that when you submit the form you are sending this payload `SUBMIT_FORM` with this object `{ name: 'John' }`, inside the main reducer you will add `case SUBMIT_FORM:` and then you will add the sent object to your main state

Comment: if you are using redux you should be able to access you state from all the component. Are you updating your state when submit?

Comment: @HaiderAli yes I'm updating my state but its not refreshing by itself when I'm going back to my main screen where all the data are displaying i have to manually refresh it by hitting  command+s then only my new data is displaying wait i will upload my code

Answer (score 0):

use an action (ex: submitAction) to update the main-list state, while you are using redux you can access any action in your app.
in your form-screen `connect` to the store and map `submitAction` to its local props and call it when the user submits.
for more details https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md

Answer (score 0):

Simply use componentWillRecieveProps, this callback function is triggered whenever there is some change in props, Use this in your main Component where you want to update the List like this

```
componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps){
  if(!isFetching && this.props.data !== nextProps.data) // or implement your preferred condition
    this.setState({UpdateList: this.props.data}) // this would call the render function
  }
}
```

You can also call Main Component function explicitly from child component when navigating back, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52581012/7462666)

Comment: I'm using redux so How do I use setState can you please have a look on code i had given

Comment: When you dispatch an Action, don't you think your props would update on the main screen component, implement componentWillRecieveProps and console.log(nextProps) to check if the props are changing, if they are changing then call setState